# I'm using PyPDF2 to search and replace text in a PDF, but I keep getting an error that says "TypeError: string indices must be integers."

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to run a Jupyter script on MacOS that can find and replace text in a PDF, but whenever I run the code, I get an error that says "TypeError: string indices must be integers." What should I be investigating to help this?

This is what the function I'm running looks like:

```
def replace_text_in_pdf(input_path, output_path, old_text, new_text):
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
        
        for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_num]
            text = page.extract_text()
            new_text = text.replace(old_text, new_text)
            page.merge_page(new_text)

            pdf_writer.addPage(page)

        with open(output_file, 'wb') as output_file:
            pdf_writer.write(output_file)
```

This is the traceback error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[152], line 7
      4 old_text = '05/11/2023 07:11 PM'
      5 new_text = str(random_datetime)
----> 7 replace_text_in_pdf(input_file, output_file, old_text, new_text)

Cell In[151], line 10, in replace_text_in_pdf(input_path, output_path, old_text, new_text)
      8     text = page.extract_text()
      9     new_text = text.replace(old_text, new_text)
---> 10     page.merge_page(new_text)
     12     pdf_writer.addPage(page)
     14 with open(output_file, 'wb') as output_file:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyPDF2/_page.py:685, in PageObject.merge_page(self, page2, expand)
    669 def merge_page(self, page2: "PageObject", expand: bool = False) -> None:
    670     """
    671     Merge the content streams of two pages into one.
    672 
   (...)
    683             expanded to accommodate the dimensions of the page to be merged.
    684     """
--> 685     self._merge_page(page2, expand=expand)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyPDF2/_page.py:714, in PageObject._merge_page(self, page2, page2transformation, ctm, expand)
    712     original_resources = DictionaryObject()
    713 try:
--> 714     page2resources = cast(DictionaryObject, page2[PG.RESOURCES].get_object())
    715 except KeyError:
    716     page2resources = DictionaryObject()

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I've tried changing PDFs and altering the length of the strings I'm trying to find and replace, but I'm not sure how to alter the dictionary.

Comment: You are expecting far too much from this line: `page.merge_page(new_text)`.
`page` in this case is a PDF Page object, but `new_text` is just a simple string.  What is the library supposed to do with that?  Where do think it's going to place that text?  PyPDF2 was not designed for this task.  You can add a new text box to a page, but you can't replace the text.